# Beautifulsoup sibling structure with br tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a HTML document using the BeautifulSoup Python library, but the structure is getting distorted by `<br>` tags. Let me just give you an example.

Input HTML:

```
<div>
  some text <br>
  <span> some more text </span> <br>
  <span> and more text </span>
</div>
```

HTML that BeautifulSoup interprets:

```
<div>
  some text
  <br>
    <span> some more text </span>
    <br>
      <span> and more text </span>
    </br>
  </br>
</div>
```

In the source, the spans could be considered siblings. After parsing (using the default parser), the spans are suddenly no longer siblings, as the br tags became part of the structure.

The solution I can think of to solve this is to strip the `<br>` tags altogether, before pouring the html into Beautifulsoup, but that doesn't seem very elegant, as it requires me to change the input. What's a better way to solve this?

Comment: Should there be two span tags there, you seem to have `<span`

Comment: Even fixing the span, i've recreated the error using bs4. bs3, however has no issues.

Comment: Indeed. The span was a typo on SO, not in my actual code. dilbert is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is to `extract()` the line breaks. It's easier than you think :).

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> html = """<div>
...   some text <br>
...   <span> some more text </span> <br>
...   <span> and more text </span>
... </div>"""
>>> soup = BS(html)
>>> for linebreak in soup.find_all('br'):
...     linebreak.extract()
... 
<br/>
<br/>
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
   some text
   <span>
    some more text
   </span>
   <span>
    and more text
   </span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nonetheless, bs4 has a problem.

Comment: Good to see it works, but I can't quite find the extract method in the Docs. What does it do?

Comment: @Joost [over here ;)](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract)

Comment: Thanks for the link! It's a bit odd to see it applied like that, because it does not really remove the content that's in between the <br> and </br> tags (the latter created by BS). Not exactly how the example works in the docs, removing the content of the <i> tag as well. Bug or Feature?

Comment: @Joost I may be wrong, but `<br>` and `</br>` are actually the same thing. It's not one of those tags that you open/close (I'm no expert in HTML). The only difference I think is that the latter is deprecated, but don't quote me.

Comment: Afaik that's `<br>` and `<br />`, which is why it suprised me greatly that BS would add a closing tag (i.e. `</br>`).

Comment: @Joost Hah, I think you're right :p. Maybe it is a bug, or maybe it's just BeautifulSoup's way of "fixing" "broken" HTML. Ty for the accept :)

Answer (score 6):

You could also do something like that:

```
str(soup).replace("</br>", "")
```

Comment: Do I need to assign the output of it to some variable?

Comment: If you want to use it somewhere, sure

Answer (score 6):

This is a super old question but I just had a similar problem because my document contained closong `</br>`tags. Because of this, massive chunks of document were simply ignored by beatifulsoup ( bs trying to deal with a closing tag, I assume.) `soup.find_all('br')` didn't actually find anything because there was no opening `br` tag, so I couldn't use the `extract()` method.

After bashing my head for an hour I found that using `lxml` parser instead of the default html fixed the problem.

`soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')`

Comment: Note it will also add redundant <html><body> tags, and what is even worse, if you have piece text which is not closed in some HTML tags, it will be wrapped by span element.

Comment: To be clear, is your comment about the lxml parser or the default one?

Comment: Well, pay attention how each parser adds uneccesary elements AND/OR auto-change invalid HTML (for example <br/> is automaticaly changed to </br>, etc.).  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers

Comment: oh ok thanks for the link. Seems like that's what most of them do, and at least lxml doesnt add <head> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more workarounds:

1. First solution works for the example because there are spaces in between, so you can remove redundant whitespaces to get text properly formatted
2. I myself had an html, where solution 1 would not work because all text parts would be concatenated without spaces. There I used workaround 2 and processed the list items afterwards.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
html = """<div>
           some text <br>
           <span> some more text </span> <br>
           <span> and more text </span>
           </div>"""
     
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

#Workaround 1
soup.find("div").text
#returns '\n   some text \n some more text  \n and more text \n'
    
#Workaround 2
[t for t in soup.find("div").children]
#and process further list items by removing br tags, whitespaces etc.
```