# Converting <br/> to <p></p> in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse text in a number of HTML documents in Python using BeautifulSoup. In the documents, some of the paragraph and newline formatting is done using `<br/>` tags, and some is done using `<p></p>` tags. I want to remove the `<br/>` tags entirely and wrap the preceding text in `<p></p>` tags prior to further processing, so the same methods can then be applied to all documents.

I've looked at the answers at [Beautifulsoup sibling structure with br tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639031/beautifulsoup-sibling-structure-with-br-tags). The answers describe how to remove the `<br>` tags altogether, but this leaves fragments of unenclosed text that cannot then be easily isolated.

I came up with a partial solution using lxml, locating previous siblings of all `<br/>` tags, and enclosing them, but since `<br/>` tags are not used in any consistent way in the documents, sometimes the previous sibling is, for example, a `<b>` or `<i>` node or another subset of the text I'm trying to wrap. The question is how to programmatically find all the text following the *previous* line break, to determine where the opening `<p>` tag should go. Is there a solution I'm not thinking of?

**I want to isolate every text segment separated from a previous text segment by a `<br/>` or other tag that makes a new line (such as closing `</p>`, etc), remove the `<br/>` tag, and wrap that segment of text in `<p></p>` tags.**

Another way to phrase the problem:  Every time the end user sees a line break, I'd like the preceding segment of text inside it's own `<p>` wrapper.

Some HTML:

```
<h3>Program</h3>
<p>Respighi - <i>Trittico Botticelliano</i>, P. 151<br>Barber - Knoxville: <i>Summer of 1915</i>, Op. 24<br>Korngold - <i>Much Ado About Nothing</i>, Op. 11: Suite</p>
<hr>
```

Example Output:

```
<h3>Program</h3>
<p>Respighi - <i>Trittico Botticelliano</i>, P. 151</p>
<p>Barber - Knoxville: <i>Summer of 1915</i>, Op. 24</p>
<p>Korngold - <i>Much Ado About Nothing</i>, Op. 11: Suite</p>
<hr>
```

UPDATE: Since the above examples are ideally simple, here's an example of some real-world HTML that should be possible to process in the same way.

```
<html>
 <body>
 <p>
 </p>
 <p>
  <span class="orangeheadline">
    Masterworks presented by EBSCO &amp; Vulcan Value Partners
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span class="boldtext">
    Justin Brown Returns! Mozart &amp; Beethoven
   <br/>
   <br/>
    Justin Brown, conductor &amp; piano
  </span>
 </p>
<br/>
<p>
  <span class="boldtext">
   Nov. 17 &amp; 18, 2017 at 8pm
  <br/>
  </span>
  <br/>
  Alys Stephens Center | Jemison Concert Hall | Map &amp; Directions
</p>
 <br/>
 <br/>
<p>
<strong>
  MOZART:
 </strong>
  Piano Concerto No. 27
  <br/>
 <strong>
 CLYNE:
 </strong>
 The Midnight Hour
 <br/>
 <strong>
 BEETHOVEN:
 </strong>
 Symphony No. 4
 <br/>
 <strong>
 </strong>
 <br/>
</p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt;">
  <span style="">
   Justin Brown returns as both conductor and pianist! Maestro Browns virtuosity shines as he leads Mozarts delightful Concerto no. 27 from the keyboard, and takes the podium to conduct Beethovens graceful Fourth Symphony.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <em>
  Gain insight into the works youre about to hear by joining us at 7pm for Concert Comments in the Reynolds-Kirschbaum Recital Hall. Free.
  </em>
 </span>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <span class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt;">
 Click here for information about the Coffee Concert
 </span>
</p>
  <br/>
  <span class="date">
    Past Event
  </span>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: But suppose that segment contains `<p>...</p>`? What then?

Comment: can you add an example and a valid output ?

Comment: @BoarGules: In that case, the closing </p> tag of the segment within the segment would result in a new line, so what I'd want to enclose the remaining text following the new line.

Comment: @ChihebNexus: done.

Comment: So, if there is a `<p>...</p>` in the identified segment between `<br/>...<br>`, like this: `<br/>A<p>B</p>C<br>` then you want the result to be `<p>A</p><p>B</p><p>C</p>`. Is that right? But what about `<p>A1<br/>A2</p><p>B</p><p>C1<br/>C2</p>`? My point is, if you're going to equate `<p>` and `<br/>` then you may have to do arbitrarily complex reparagraphing.

Comment: @BoarGules: To the first part, yes, that is the result I'd be looking for. To the second part, also yes; but it's not so much me equating the two tags as trying to put structure into documents with inconsistent format. And you're right it may become arbitrarily complex. There may be a simpler solution but I haven't thought of it. A simpler way to phrase the problem: Every time the end user sees a new line, I'd like that segment of text inside it's own <p> wrapper. And I suppose the <p> wrapper itself is even arbitrary ; any enclosure that would allow isolating the text node works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some `find`-`extract` magic with re-building the container tag can do something like that apparently (the originally proposed `replace_with` could not)

```
import bs4
html="""
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- <p> -->
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>
      consectetur <b>adipiscing</b> elit,<br>
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br>
      ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    <!-- </p> -->
  </body>
</html>"""
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
print("Before:")
print(soup.prettify())
root=soup.find('br').parent
p=soup.new_tag('p')
for x in list(root.contents):
  if x.name=='br':
    if(p.contents):
      x.insert_before(p)
    p=soup.new_tag('p')
  else:
    p.contents.append(x)
  x.extract()
if(p.contents):
  root.contents.append(p)
if(root.name=='p'):
  root.unwrap()
print()
print("After:")
print(soup.prettify())
print("Re-parsed:")
print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(soup),"lxml").prettify())
```

The code locates a `<br>` tag, then works on its parent (referred as root inside) and wraps everything into `<p>`-s between the `<br>` tags it encounters. Not very clean code, but works to some extent.
If the root happens to be a `<p>` tag already, it is unwrapped (you can test it by uncommenting that `<p>`-`</p>` pair)
It preserves sub-tags (like the bold thing here), but it is also its weakness, as all of those sub-tags will go inside the nearest `<p>`. It is less of a problem with the comments here, but it would look weird if there were headings for example, or practically any block elements.

The immediate output looks ugly, so I show the re-parsed one one only :-)

> ```
> <html>
>  <body>
>   <p>
>    <!-- <p> -->
>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   </p>
>   <p>
>    consectetur
>    <b>
>     adipiscing
>    </b>
>    elit,
>   </p>
>   <p>
>    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
>   </p>
>   <p>
>    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>    <!-- </p> -->
>   </p>
>  </body>
> </html>
> ```

---

Generally it works with the deliberately wicked example too, 2 things are modified:

1. It runs in a loop as long as it encounters more `<br>` tags. And I had to re-parse the HTML for each iteration, somehow a simple `find` was not enough
2. Apparently new 'empty' `<p>` tags were already containing a line-break, so this strange empty-ness check was introduced: `if("".join([str(y) for y in p.contents]).strip()):` (for added fun, the string-conversion of the elements was necessary too)

Otherwise:

```
import bs4
html="""
<html>
 <body>
 <p>
 </p>
 <p>
  <span class="orangeheadline">
Masterworks presented by EBSCO &amp; Vulcan Value Partners
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span class="boldtext">
    Justin Brown Returns! Mozart &amp; Beethoven
   <br/>
   <br/>
    Justin Brown, conductor &amp; piano
  </span>
 </p>
<br/>
<p>
  <span class="boldtext">
   Nov. 17 &amp; 18, 2017 at 8pm
  <br/>
  </span>
  <br/>
  Alys Stephens Center | Jemison Concert Hall | Map &amp; Directions
</p>
 <br/>
 <br/>
<p>
<strong>
  MOZART:
 </strong>
  Piano Concerto No. 27
  <br/>
 <strong>
 CLYNE:
 </strong>
 The Midnight Hour
 <br/>
 <strong>
 BEETHOVEN:
 </strong>
 Symphony No. 4
 <br/>
 <strong>
 </strong>
 <br/>
</p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt;">
  <span style="">
   Justin Brown returns as both conductor and pianist! Maestro Browns virtuosity shines as he leads Mozarts delightful Concerto no. 27 from the keyboard, and takes the podium to conduct Beethovens graceful Fourth Symphony.
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <em>
  Gain insight into the works youre about to hear by joining us at 7pm for Concert Comments in the Reynolds-Kirschbaum Recital Hall. Free.
  </em>
 </span>
 <br/>
 <br/>
 <span class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 0.0001pt;">
 Click here for information about the Coffee Concert
 </span>
</p>
  <br/>
  <span class="date">
    Past Event
  </span>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</body>  
</html>"""
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
print("Before:")
print(soup.prettify())

br=soup.find('br')
while br:
  root=br.parent
  p=soup.new_tag('p')
  for x in list(root.contents):
    if x.name=='br':
      if("".join([str(y) for y in p.contents]).strip()):
        x.insert_before(p)
      p=soup.new_tag('p')
    else:
      p.contents.append(x)
    x.extract()
  if("".join([str(y) for y in p.contents]).strip()):
    root.contents.append(p)
  if(root.name=='p'):
    root.unwrap()
  soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(soup),"lxml")
  br=soup.find('br')

print()
print("After:")
print(soup.prettify())
print("Re-parsed:")
print(bs4.BeautifulSoup(str(soup),"lxml").prettify())
```

Comment: @NFB See if this one helps - I am not sure if you get notification for a mere edit, so I add this comment too.

Comment: Definitely a start, but there are a lot of use cases where this will not work, as it identifies the parent of the first <br> tag as root, when the actual "root" document to process may be higher in the tree. I'm updating the question with some more problematic HTML.

Comment: @NFB: see things added (below the example output)

Comment: Very impressed. This works, I just need to fiddle with the code for a bit so I fully understand why (there are a few steps I don't understand) -- then I'll mark this as answered. You're right, that second HTML example is a real mess.

Comment: Why is it necessary to rebuild the soup at the end of the while loop? I see that it works, but I don't understand why the original soup object was not modified accordingly during the loop.

Comment: @NFB I do not know, when I issued that 'find' again, it found 'None' and exited the loop. The object itself is modified for sure, since that is the one passed to 'str()'. It may have something to do with that the immediate prettified output has issues with the hieararchy, and that also gets fixed after re-parsing and prettifying again. It may store some state interfering further actions, but I can not tell if I am using it wrong or it is an actual bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
text = '''<h3>Program</h3>
<p>Respighi - <i>Trittico Botticelliano</i>, P. 151<br>Barber - 
 Knoxville: <i>Summer of 1915</i>, Op. 24<br>Korngold - <i>Much Ado About Nothing</i>, Op. 11: Suite</p>
<hr>'''
new_text = re.sub('\<br\>', '</p>\n<p>', text)
```

Output:

```
<h3>Program</h3>
<p>Respighi - <i>Trittico Botticelliano</i>, P. 151</p>
<p>Barber - Knoxville: <i>Summer of 1915</i>, Op. 24</p>
<p>Korngold - <i>Much Ado About Nothing</i>, Op. 11: Suite</p>
<hr>
```

Comment: That is a simple solution that didn't occur to me. What if, however, there is no original opening p tag, so that the added closing tag doesn't close anything? My example was just an example, and probably an overly ideal one.

Comment: I'm already using that library (see above), and it does do some pre-validating of the HTML, but that does not include adding opening tags to orphan closing tags.

Comment: @NFB is it guaranteed that each line ends with `\n`?

Comment: No -- it's all dependent on HTML tags.