# Text inside BR not fetch using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to get all data inside div under br tags. however it only fetch the text on the first .

```
<div itemprop="description">

<p>Chars :
</br>- test1 
</br>- test2 
</br>- test3
</p>

</div>
```

script:

```
tag = soup.find(itemprop="description").get_text()
```

output:

```
Chars
-test1
```

I want to get all text inside br

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639031/beautifulsoup-sibling-structure-with-br-tags/44935244#44935244

BS is known to interact weirdly with `br` tags. Your options could be 1) removing br tags  like `str(soup).replace("</br>", "")`  or using a different parser: `soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')` (The second option worked well for me)

Comment: thanks it did solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't had a problem with lxml and select

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''
<div itemprop="description">

<p>Chars :
</br>- test1 
</br>- test2 
</br>- test3
</p>

</div>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
data = [item.text.strip().replace('\n',' ') for item in soup.select('div[itemprop=description]')]
print(data)
```