# get_text() problem managing tag inside text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract data from html table and obviously I'm using `BeatifulSoup`

I managed to select relevant tags and organize data into a pandas df.
I have one little problem I need to solve.

For example suppose i have a variable `column` which is an instance of `bs4.element.Tag` whose value is equal to:

```
<td>Valore di inizio<br/>esercizio</td>
```

When i call `column.get_text()` it returns:

```
Valore di inizioesercizio
```

I'd like to have back

```
Valore di inizio esercizio
```

i.e tag `br` should be stripped and replaced with a space.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautifulsoup sibling structure with br tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639031/beautifulsoup-sibling-structure-with-br-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `get_text()` but with `separator=` parameter:

```
data = '''<td>Valore di inizio<br/>esercizio</td>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print(soup.td.get_text(separator=' '))  # for more control, you can add strip=True parameter
```

Prints:

```
Valore di inizio esercizio
```