# Scraping badly coded html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I scraped a website that has hundreds of pages of badly organized HTML. I used BeautifulSoup to capture all the content of a div on each page. The excerpt of that list is:

```py
mylist = [['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/31/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92112<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/29/2019<br/>03:02:38 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019<br/></div>'],
['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92086<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/28/2019<br/>02:55:39 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019<br/></div>'],
['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/28/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92074<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/27/2019<br/>03:14:16 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019<br/></div>']]
```

How do I capture what is in between the `<br/>` tags, including blanks when there is nothing between them?

I should have added that the output should become a list of lists with each item in separate by a `<br/>` tag is a item in the list. For example:

```
[['"006951446", "Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC", "Critical notice", "12/30/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "12/31/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "92112", "Initiate", "Capacity Constraint", "12/29/2019", "03:02:38 PM", "No response required", "AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019"'],
 ['"006951446", "Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC", "Critical notice", "12/29/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "12/30/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "92086", "Initiate", "Capacity Constraint", "12/28/2019", "02:55:39 PM", "No response required", "AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019"'],
 ['"006951446", "Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC", "Critical notice", "12/28/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "12/29/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "92074", "Initiate", "Capacity Constraint", "12/27/2019", "03:14:16 PM", "No response required", "AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019"']]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand can you give a small example to demonstrate what you want instead of all that text in mylist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
mylist = [['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/31/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92112<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/29/2019<br/>03:02:38 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019<br/></div>'],
          ['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92086<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/28/2019<br/>02:55:39 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019<br/></div>'],
          ['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/28/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92074<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/27/2019<br/>03:14:16 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019<br/></div>']]

for item in mylist:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(*item, 'html.parser')
    print(*[a.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|") for a in soup])
```

Output:

```
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/31/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92112', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/29/2019', '03:02:38 PM', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 
12/30/2019']
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92086', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/28/2019', '02:55:39 PM', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 
12/29/2019']
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/28/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92074', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/27/2019', '03:14:16 PM', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 
12/28/2019']
```

Comment: This is really close. But I need each item in the list to be a separate item in the list. Like:

```
[['"006951446", "Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC", "Critical notice", "12/30/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "12/31/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "92112", "Initiate", "Capacity Constraint", "12/29/2019", "03:02:38 PM", "No response required", "AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019"'],
 ['"006951446", "Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC", "Critical notice", "12/29/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "12/30/2019", "09:00:00 AM", "92086", "Initiate", "Capacity Constraint"']]
```

Comment: thanks! i noticed that right before the "No response required" part, there are some `<br\>` with nothing in them. In the whole data, there are times when those hold some numbers. How to capture those as empty items and with data when there is data.

Comment: @SMJune you've receive an answer based on your example. good luck

Answer (score 1):

Usually,when you use select on a `BeatifulSoup` object,you get a list of `Tag`s.
And you can use `select`/`getText` on the `Tag`s again.
For exsample:

```py
SEP='(--*--SEP--*--)'
mylist=soup.select('div')
between_br=[[j for j in i.getText(SEP).split(SEP) if not j.isspace()] for i in mylist]
```

Comment: Hi, am getting an error on this one that says: SelectorSyntaxError: Invalid character '/' position 2
  line 1:
br/

Comment: Fixed,it this your wanted output?https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/F5x4nmbN2z/

Comment: It's to big to paste into a comment and the formatting will be terrable.  
Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, it might be hard to give an exact answer but [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup) is a great package for this. You should be able to continue using the `bs4` package to comb through the HTML using a combination of `BeautifulSoup` methods.(e.g. `find`/`find_all`/`select` etc.)

[See this answer for help on br tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639031/beautifulsoup-sibling-structure-with-br-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions using library SimplifiedDoc.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
mylist = [['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/31/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92112<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/29/2019<br/>03:02:38 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019<br/></div>'],
          ['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92086<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/28/2019<br/>02:55:39 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019<br/></div>'],
          ['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/28/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92074<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/27/2019<br/>03:14:16 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019<br/></div>']]
values = []
# First way
for item in mylist:
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(item[0])
  tmp = doc.selects('br').nextText()
  tmp.insert(0,doc.div.firstText())
  values.append(tmp)
values = []
# Second way
for item in mylist:
  doc = SimplifiedDoc(item[0])
  brs = doc.selects('br')
  tmp = [br.previousText() for br in brs]
  values.append(tmp)
print(values)
```

Result:

```
[['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/31/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92112', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/29/2019', '03:02:38 PM', '', '', 'No response required', '', '', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019'], ['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92086', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/28/2019', '02:55:39 PM', '', '', 'No response required', '', '', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019'], ['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/28/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92074', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/27/2019', '03:14:16 PM', '', '', 'No response required', '', '', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019']]
```