# Follow up question: uneven html leads to imbalance in python list

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is a follow up to this question: [Scraping badly coded html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860521/scraping-badly-coded-html)

I noticed that of the hundreds of pages scraped, most have no information between specific `<br\>` tags. But once in a while the `<br\>` tags in that position hold some information. So the excerpt below has `<br/>92524<br/>` in the last list item while the others are simply `<br\><br\>`

```
mylist = [['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/31/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92112<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/29/2019<br/>03:02:38 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019<br/></div>'],
['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/30/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92086<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/28/2019<br/>02:55:39 PM<br/> <br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019<br/></div>'],
['<div id="headingData">006951446<br/>Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC<br/>Critical notice<br/>12/28/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>12/29/2019<br/>09:00:00 AM<br/>92074<br/>Initiate<br/>Capacity Constraint<br/>12/27/2019<br/>03:14:16 PM<br/>92524<br/><br/>No response required<br/> <br/> <br/>AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019<br/></div>']]
```

The code provided by [ahmed american](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658985/%CE%B1%D4%8B%C9%B1%D2%BD%D4%83-%CE%B1%D0%BC%D1%94%D1%8F%CE%B9c%CE%B1%CE%B7)(thank you!) worked perfectly on the data i had originally provided which did not include the issue above.

```
for item in mylist:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(*item, 'html.parser')
    print(*[a.get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|") for a in soup])
```

But when you run it on the updated list above, you get lists that have an imbalance. When there is info in that position, it is captured and a list item is created. If there is no info, that position is not turned into a list item. That leads of uneven lists.

You can see the imbalance if you scroll to the right and look at the `'No response required',` item.

```
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/31/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92112', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/29/2019', '03:02:38 PM', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019']
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92086', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/28/2019', '02:55:39 PM', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019']
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/28/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92074', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/27/2019', '03:14:16 PM', '92524', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019']
```

How do you tweak the code so that any `<br\>` tags with nothing in between them just get a "NA" marker and all the resulting lists remain aligned?

Answer (score 0):

I think I came up with a workaround. I checked the len of each item in the list. If it is only 14, then I insert into the 12th index position the string "NA".

```
if len(item) == 14:
    item.insert(12, "NA")
```

This correctly returns:

```
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/31/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92112', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/29/2019', '03:02:38 PM', 'NA', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/30/2019']
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/30/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92086', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/28/2019', '02:55:39 PM','NA', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/29/2019']
['006951446', 'Algonquin Gas Transmission, LLC', 'Critical notice', '12/28/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '12/29/2019', '09:00:00 AM', '92074', 'Initiate', 'Capacity Constraint', '12/27/2019', '03:14:16 PM', '92524', 'No response required', 'AGT Pipeline Conditions for 12/28/2019']
```