# problem with selecting a tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a tag like below that I want to select it with [`Beautiful Soup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```html
<td align="right" class="simcal" valign="top"> Title:<br/></td>
```

When I try to select this tag with the following codes everything is ok.

```py
# sample 1 :
my_tag = soup.find(
            'td',
            attrs={"align": "right", "class": "header2", "valign": 'top'},
        )
# sample 2 :
my_tag = soup.find(
            text=" Title:",
            attrs={"align": "right", "class": "header2", "valign": 'top'},
        )
```

But when i try to combine these two together [`Beautiful Soup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) can not find the element which I want.

```py
# This will fail
my_tag = soup.find(
            'td',
            text=" Title:",
            attrs={"align": "right", "class": "header2", "valign": 'top'},
        )
```

So my question here is can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's a typo in this. You have it look for `class="header2"` when in your html it's `"simcal"`

Secondly, (this is just my understanding, I can't say for certain) but the text `" Title:"` is within a `<br>` tag with not attributes. So it's correct in that it doesn't return anything with the attributes `align="right" class="simcal" valign="top"` as that belongs the the `<td>` tag. What is tricky here is that for html, you don't need to open with a `<br>` tag, which I think is why BeautifulSoup is getting tripped up here.

Notice, if we remove the `</br>` tag, it works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<td align="right" class="header2" valign="top"> Title:</td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
my_tag = soup.find(
            'td',
            text=" Title:",
            attrs={"align": "right", "class": "header2", "valign": 'top'},
        )

print(my_tag)
```

**Output:**

```
<td align="right" class="header2" valign="top"> Title:</td>
```

To fix this in your case though without having to remove closing `</br>` tags, and with help from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639031/beautifulsoup-sibling-structure-with-br-tags), we see by using a `'lxml'` parser in stead of `'html.parser'`, it can deal with it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<td align="right" class="header2" valign="top"> Title:</br></td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

# sample 1 :
my_tag1 = soup.find(
            'td',
            attrs={"align": "right", "class": "header2", "valign": 'top'},
        )
# sample 2 :
my_tag2 = soup.find(
            text=" Title:",
            attrs={"align": "right", "class": "header2", "valign": 'top'},
        )

my_tag3 = soup.find(
            'td',
            text=" Title:",
            attrs={"align": "right", "class": "header2", "valign": 'top'},
        )



print(my_tag1)
print(my_tag2)
print(my_tag3)
```

**Output:**

```
<td align="right" class="header2" valign="top"> Title:</td>
<td align="right" class="header2" valign="top"> Title:</td>
<td align="right" class="header2" valign="top"> Title:</td>
```